# Passing parameters to GET in REST

Tags: rest, jersey

I am trying to pass parameters with a GET request to a REST web service:

My class has the path defined as follows:

```
@Path("/ws")
 public class RegistrationWS {
```

The method that I am calling has the path defined as:

```
@GET
@Produces("text/plain")
@Path("/{key}/{deviceId}")
public String getText(@QueryParam("key") String key, @QueryParam("deviceId") String deviceId) {
```

When I run the client, I get back the word 'failure', which is what my getText() method returns if the key was null:

```
        // Get plain text
    String registrationResponse = service.path("rest").path("ws/"+DEF+"/"+"ABC")
                                                      .accept(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
                                                      .get(String.class);
```

Am I building the URL correctly in the client?

Comment: You have to use `@PathParam` with `@Path ` annotation, not `@QueryParam`

Comment: Ok, would my client side have to change?